# Optimize evaluation time for a Quantum Walk simulation

Tags: evaluation, performance-tuning

Here's the problem. I'm trying to simulate a noisy Quantum Walk to obtain results similar to [these, experimentally obtained](http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v7/n4/abs/nphoton.2013.26.html).

I wrote my code, and I get results which are in accordance to what I expected.

The problem is, my evaluation time is too high. In the article they achieve a simulation of a 100-step QW, but I have to wait up to 5 hours just to get a 16-step result.

These are the time-consuming lines of code:

```
finalstate = 
  ParallelTable[
    Expand[
      Nest[TotalF, 
        state[1, 1, -1, j] state[2, 0, 1, j] - 
          state[1, 0, -1, j] state[2, 1, 1, j], 
        length]], 
    {j, 1, jmax}];

probabilities = 
  ParallelTable[
    Table[{i, k, 
      Total[
        Cases[Expand @ finalstate[[j]], 
          a___ state[1, _, i, _] state[2, _, k, _] :> 
            Abs[If[a === Null, 1, a]]^2]]}, 
        {i, -length - 10, length + 10}, 
        {k, -length - 10, length + 10}], 
     {j, 1, jmax}];
```

Where `TotalF` is defined as such:

```
phase = 
  Table[
    Table[{Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, ϕmax}]], Exp[I*RandomReal[{0, ϕmax}]]}, 
      {i, -length - 10, length + 10}], 
    {j, 1, jmax}];

TotalF[state[index_, coin : (0 | 1), position_, conf_]] := 
  Module[{row = position + length + 3, col = If[coin == 0, 1, 2]}, 
    1/Sqrt[2] * phase[[conf, row, col]] * 
      (state[index, 0, position + 1, conf] + 
         If[coin == 0, 1, -1] state[index, 1, position - 1, conf])];

TotalF[u_ + v_] := TotalF[u] + TotalF[v];
TotalF[u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_] := u TotalF[v];
TotalF[u_ v_] := TotalF[u] TotalF[v];
```

`ϕmax`, `length` and `jmax` are constants.

Now, evaluating `finalstate` takes 2.5 seconds for 8 steps and 680 seconds for 16 steps. Evaluating `probabilities` takes 37 seconds for 8 steps and a lot more (about 5 hours, didn't try it with AbsoluteTiming) for 16 steps, so if I could at least speed up this last part (although if I want to achieve the 100-steps result I'd have to optimize the first one as well) it would be great.

I hope I made myself clear enough, I'm willing to provide extra information if needed.

Comment: Could you narrow down the most time-consuming parts? The whole hog is somewhat unattractive to reverse-engineer.

Comment: I'll do it right away.

Comment: You dropped `phase` which is vital to the definition of `TotalF`.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed. Sorry about that, I'll correct immediately.

Comment: I cannot execute your code for probabilities:    Expression "{i,k,Total[Cases[Expand@finalstate[[j]],a___state[1,_,i,_]state[2,_,k,_]:>Abs[If[a===Null,1,a]]^2]],{i,-length-10,length+10},{k,-length-10,length+10}" has no closing "}".

Comment: I forgot to copy that, in my notebook it was correct. Now it is here, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. It's working (really well) for 1 particle, but needs to be checked for two particles, I guess due to minor mistakes.

Basically, I changed approach and turned to a matrix notation.

Let's start from the one-particle system.
We simply write the state as a vector, and the operators as matrices, being very careful about the indexing.

So, for a system of length $2L+1$ (that means an evolution over $L$ steps starting from position 0), the state is a tensor product of the position vector and the coin vector:

```
posInitialState = Table[
    Normal[
     SparseArray[
       length[[v]] + 1 -> 1, 2*length[[v]] + 1]], {v, 1,lmax}];

coinInitialState = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1/Sqrt[2], I/Sqrt[2]}};
```

where the position space has dimension $2L+1$ and the coin space has dimension $2$. `length[[v]]` is simply an array which determines the length of the QW, as defined in the question.

We then define the displacement and coin operators:

```
displacementMatrix[v_] := 
    DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[ConstantArray[{1, 0}, 2*length[[v]]]], 2] + 
    DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 2*length[[v]]]], -2];


staticCoinMatrix = 
    Table[
     KroneckerProduct[
       DiagonalMatrix[Exp[I RandomReal[{0, ϕmax[[u]]},2 length[[v]] +1]]],
       HadamardMatrix[2]], {u,1,fmax},{v,1,lmax}];
```

Now the evolution after $L$ steps is, of course, given by the $n-th$ power of the product of these two:

```
unitaryStaticEvolution[u_,v_]:=
    MatrixPower[displacementMatrix[v].staticCoinMatrix[[u,v]], length[[v]]];
```

Now it's straightforward: let's define the initial state in the total Hilbert space:

```
initialState = Table[Flatten[
   KroneckerProduct[posInitialState[[v]], coinInitialState[[0]]]], 
    {v, 1, lmax}];
```

and

```
finalstate = ParallelTable[
state = 
Table[ unitaryStaticEvolution[u, v].initialState[[v]], {j, 1, jmax}];
state2 = 
Table[Abs[state[[j, 1 ;; -2 ;; 2]]]^2 + 
  Abs[state[[j, 2 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]^2, {j, 1, jmax}];
Mean[state2[[1 ;; -1]]]
, {u, 1, fmax}, {v, 1, lmax}
];
```

Finally, we get our probabilities in a nice table, ready to be plotted:

```
probabilities = Table[
    Partition[Riffle[
         Table[i,{i,-length[[v]],length[[v]]}],
         finalstate[[u,v]]],2],
    {u,1,fmax},{v,1,lmax}];
```

For two particles, it should be quite the same. We could define the states and operators as tensor products of the single-particle states, and do the same thing.
I'm still working on it, though, as

```
static2pEvo[u_,v_]:
KroneckerProduct[unitaryStaticEvolution[u,v],unitaryStaticEvolution[u,v]];
```

does not give me something I can work on.
What I get in this case are probabilities which are the same for every length or noise configuration.

But the approach is correct, as it works for 1 particle, and gives me results that are way faster than the older ones (not having to deal with pattern matchings).

---

EDIT: ok, I got the error, there was a mistake in the coin operator's definition. Now it's corrected here as well, and it works for both 1 and 2 particles.

---

RE-EDIT: alas, the approach is correct but, if the former approach got too much time to compute, this one consumes the whole RAM (I have 16GB), as for large dimensions the matrix sizes grow up to $10^{5}\times 10^{5}$, which means a very large RAM usage...

Answer (score 7):

There are two parts that are immediately suspicious to me: your `phase` calculation and `finalState`.

Your calculation of `phase` is rather inefficient. `Table` is a good construct, but it is often slow. The form you have is not even allowing it to speed things up: you are nesting them instead of using both iterators with one call.  Honestly, I would not even bother with `Table` and use the vector properties of `Exp`, e.g.

```
phase = Exp[I RandomReal[{0, \[Phi]max}, {jmax, 2 length + 21, 2}]];
```

which generates a packed array.

Second, in trying to determine what a single element of `finalstate` gives you, I ran into speed issues with only iterations. At issue is at each iteration of `Nest`, `TotalF` must go through a progressively larger expression and it is not very fast at doing so. The simpler thing to do is to expand the expression at each iteration,

```
Nest[
  Expand[TotalF[#]]&,
  state[1, 1, -1, j] state[2, 0, 1, j] - state[1, 0, -1, j] state[2, 1, 1, j],
  length
]
```

which simplifies the job `TotalF` has to do. On my computer, this easily works through `length == 16`. Of course, with a `length` greater than 16, I get `$RecursionLimit::reclim2` messages, so I will have to think on how to better approach this.

---

The `$RecursionLimit::reclim2` messages limit messages can be eliminated by changing how `TotalF` handles `Plus`. `Map` over `Plus` instead of handling it pairwise:

```
TotalF[a_Plus] := TotalF /@ a
```

We could do something similar for Times, as well, and it lends itself to a nice simplification:

```
Clear[TotalF];
TotalF[state[index_,coin:(0|1),position_,conf_]]:=
Module[{row=position+length+3,col=If[coin==0,1,2]},
   1/Sqrt[2]*phase[[conf,row,col]]*(state[index,0,position+1,conf]
         +If[coin==0,1,-1] state[index,1,position-1,conf])
];

TotalF[a:_Plus|_Times]:=TotalF/@a
TotalF[a_] := a
```

On my machine, just mapping over `Plus` with a `length` of 50 took 23 s, but eliminating the `PatternTest`, (`u_?(FreeQ[#, state] &) v_`), dropped the time it took to 15 s. A nice improvement, especially if run in parallel.

---

`probabilities` will require more thought.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't put my focus on `phase` simply because it remains constant once generated, and as it takes less than a second it's not a big deal. But yeah, anything helps, so thanks again!

Comment: Right, it isn't the bottle neck, but it is referenced, a lot, and there were issues with its generation that extend to the rest of the code. So, we improve one bit, to show you how to improve others.

Comment: You're right. Now that I think about it, when `length` becomes higher I could use some more speed to generate `phase` as well.

Comment: I just updated this. I'll look at `probabilities`, later.

Comment: Wow, the improvement looks very big! Could you tell me why it is possible to eliminate the `PatternTest`? I mean, what does that final `TotalF[a_]:=a` do?

Comment: Well, you only want `TotalF` to work on `state`s, per the first down value ([ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html)). So, `TotalF[a_]:=a` is just a pass through for the coefficients. Without it, `TotalF[5 state[...]]` would produce `TotalF[5] TotalF[state[...]]` and `TotalF[5]` would remain unevaluated. `PatternTest`, because here it is using user code, evaluates slower than a plain pattern (`a_`). So, use it, if you have to, but opt for plain patterns when possible.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to thank you for the answer, sorry about that.
Anyway, I ran a test run with a 3-particle system, and (with a length equal to 4) I got the result in about 6-7 hours. I know this is due to the scaling of the problem (should be scaling with the factorial of the number of particles and with the factorial of twice the length, or something like that). Should I try running `finalstate` and `probabilities` separately, so as to check the correct evaluation times?

Comment: I'm still thinking. I want to recast this as a matrix problem, but it is thus far resisting. So, thinking ...

Comment: I found a way to "port" the problem to a matrix notation (but I'm still having problems with the implementation in Mathematica), which should make things easier, theoretically. Should I edit the original post or write it as an answer?

Comment: @Enzo good question. You could post it as an answer with the note that it is a partial answer and still needs some details fleshed out. That way, you don't get dinged for posting something that doesn't work.

Comment: Good! As soon as I get home I'll post it, then.

Comment: Can I get the email of either of you @Enzo or @rcollyer? I have just started learning the quantum walk problem. I am stuck with a very simple example-a two step q-walk. I tried to upload the problem on stackexchange.com but for some strange reason, could not.